# Is a subject/tag-specific "how to ask questions" question better on meta or SO?

Tags: discussion

I want to post a canonical Q&A pair on how to write good, minimized, self-contained questions focusing specifically on C++ *and* the Qt toolkit, when used together. I'm tired of telling everyone the same thing in comments, and it would be much more fleshed out and useful in a Q&A format.

The [help center article on MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is too general and too abstract to be of much help to people who don't know enough to connect the abstractions with the concrete features of the programming language and the framework in question (C++, Qt).

I want to specifically provide tangible, compileable examples of the minimization work, and specific tips and tricks that lead to good, concise and to-the-point code that illustrates a problem one might have. These tricks are to specifically employ the power of C++, its standard library, the Qt framework, and the code generators and other tools that you get with Qt.

Does such a thing belong on meta, or on SO itself? The answer would have quite a bit of code minimization tips that are toolkit- and language-specific, so it's not a general "how to ask good questions" Q&A, but one specific to C++ and Qt, demonstrating the methods and how to leverage the toolkit's and language's strengths to write succinct, to-the-point test cases/examples that reproduce the issue at hand.

The question would be tagged [c++] [qt] [qt4] [qt5] if it were to appear on SO.

Comment: It's already present in the help center, why do you think writing your version should provide improvement for this already available information? If you feel [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needs improvement ask for a feature request here, and explicitly state, what you think should be improved or added.

Comment: To be clear, such a question does not belong on SO itself.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, it's not present in the help center, because - again - I'm talking of language- and framework-specific hints that few newbie askers seem to know about.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan So, a question about how to minimize test cases utilizing a particular set of tools doesn't belong on SO? Is that not a programming question?

Comment: @KubaOber Well, we expect users being creative enough to extrapolate the guidelines given there, to make it happen for their specific language tag, IDE or build system. I don't believe this would be a good canonical, neither on StackOverflow, nor on Meta-SO.

Comment: If you're talking about minimizing test cases for general consumption, sure. If you're talking about how to ask a good question about the frameworks on SO, no.

Comment: @KubaOber - I think by "SO itself", Mike is talking about the main SO site, not both SO and Meta.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "we expect users being creative enough to extrapolate the guidelines given there" Anyone with teaching experience would say that this is a very naive and borderline inhumane or fantastical viewpoint. Ideally, we would want it to be so. Practically speaking, it's not happening. When you add language barriers, low familiarity with subject matter, etc., our brains simply don't work this way - it's very hard to reconcile abstract rules with concrete, actionable steps that can be followed. **I want to specifically address this pedagogical shortcoming**. I can't see how it is harmful.

Comment: @KubaOber We aren't supposed being nannying or teaching here. That's far beyond of the sites actual goals.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK. Suppose I post it on a blog or github page or whatnot. I don't care much where it goes. I now imagine I'll be commenting on downvoted questions giving a link to this resource, and people will be flagging the comments claiming that I shouldn't be pointing to off-site resources, or saying that it's not "official" (since it doesn't come from SO or meta). And I worry whether the link to such a non-monetized resource will be shot down from the tag wiki, even if helpful. Do you promise to have the restraint not to worry about that, and not to shoot such a resource down? (I'm serious)

Comment: The whole reason I really wished it belonged somewhere on SO or meta was that I don't want to try to give an impression that I try to funnel a traffic to an off-site resource that's my own, even if it'd be open-source, stand-alone page (not a blog) and not monetized. I don't want to give anyone any ammunition, even if they would be wrong believing I had some ulterior motive other than helping out. I simply want to be 100% above the board. I just find that I'm repeating myself, and that many questions would benefit from the same tricks to make them clearer or more useful to the wider community.

Answer (score 5):

Information on how to ask an appropriate question for a particular tag, if the information is truly unique to that tag, should be included in that tag's wiki.

Comment: I don't think I've ever clicked on the "Learn More" links for any of the popular tags. I've only ever done that for tags I don't recognize and they're always either really short or empty. This whole time I could have been telling people who are new to look at info in the tags.

Comment: Suppose though, that there are various tricks that you could include, and perhaps that knowledge is particular enough to be rewarded by reputation. Also, different people might offer different approaches - that's what a canonical Q&A would be good for. Are you really sure that a Q&A that potentially could have multiple answers, and be a good couple of screenfuls long, belongs in the Q&A wiki? Do we have any Q&A wikis with such detailed question-asking techniques? Can you point to one? If not, I don't think that the wiki would be a good fit.

Comment: @KubaOber You should be posting widely accepted principles of that tag's community, not just your personal preferences that will vary widely from the ideas of other contributors.  Such personal opinions don't belong in any canonical resource.

Comment: What I'm aiming at isn't necessarily "how to ask an appropriate question", but how to proceed so that *at the end* you get an appropriate question. The process is way more than a mere "how" would suggest.

Comment: @Servy Good, then we have established that such a Q&A is not fit for a tag wiki. So, where else does it belong? Since it is directly related to programming and technique, it seems that SO would be reasonable, but since it is about *how* of question asking, I thought meta might be better. It is, literally *how to do the programming-y things so that you end up with a good question*. So yes, it's about programming, but it happens to be about question asking too, as it relates to a particular tag. My main gripe is that people don't realize how easy it is to write concise test cases with Qt.

Comment: @KubaOber That's a description of information on how to ask an appropriate question.

Comment: @KubaOber If it's just your personal preferences, and not widely accepted community practices on how to ask an appropriate question, then post it on your personal blog.  It doesn't belong on the site at all.

Comment: @Servy Given that my goal is to merely concretize the abstract notion of MCVE as applied to C++/Qt, I wouldn't necessarily call it a personal preference. As long as we consider MCVE to be the goal, there's a bunch of techniques/rules that you have to apply no matter what to reach the minimalized, readable, understandable outcome. As long as the MCVE aspect is not a personal preference, the particular steps you have to apply to reach it can't be one either, if there's literally no other way of reaching it.

Comment: @KubaOber So then you *are* talking about widely accepted community practices rather than controversial personal preferences?  Whichever case you have, you have your answer.

Comment: @Servy Even the main C++ tag has *nothing* about how to ask good C++ questions in it - it doesn't do anything to concretize the MCVE as it applies to C++. Even though there are plenty of widely accepted community practices as to minimization of C++ examples/test cases, you find *none of it* in the C++ tag wiki. So I'm almost certain that none of would belong in the Qt wiki as well. Unless you posit that the C++ tag wiki is woefully inadequate, and we're past overdue to add some practical question asking tips to it.

Comment: Literally the only practical guideline in the C++ wiki is "Try to keep the code as minimal as possible while still being able to reproduce the problem; often the problem will be found during the process of creating that sample code." Nothing there on how to leverage the unique properties of C++ to actually accomplish that (merging of translation units, removal of include guards and other junk, java-style implementations-in-class-declarations where it makes things easier to read and smaller, etc.).

Comment: @KubaOber I'm not saying that all tags are obligated to spent considerable time explaining how to ask questions.  I'm saying that if you have information on how to ask an appropriate question that's completely unique to a particular tag (rather than asking questions in general), that information would be entirely appropriate in that tag's wiki.

Comment: @KubaOber So you're saying that the tag wiki already describes exactly the issue you want to talk about, it just does so briefly rather than with more specific detail.  What about that makes you think that such information is completely inappropriate in that context then?

Comment: The thing is: some of the tips apply to C++, some to Qt, so I'd like to modify both wikis. I don't see any of such tips being applicable to the C++ wiki, since there'd be likely an outrage about the wiki suddenly being 4x as long, even if I'd keep myself very succinct. That's why I think that outsourcing that stuff to a Q&A has a higher chance of success and of reconciling input from multiple people.

Comment: "What about that makes you think that such information is completely inappropriate in that context then?" Since nobody bothered with expanding it, and C++ isn't exactly an unpopular tag. I fully expect that I'd be told to go to hell for adding such details. So I don't see it happening for reasons other than normal, expected human inertia... Sure, I could give it a try, but do you really think that a tag wiki can have 50%+ of content that gives specific question-asking techniques used to make the code easier for ones to swallow, and to find bugs in?

Comment: @KubaOber If you have a bunch of information that's not actually applicable to questions of a particular tag you should indeed not be editing it into that tag's wiki.  If you think that it would take that much text to explain what you want to explain than I can tell you now people aren't going to read it no matter where you put it; you need to spent quite a lot of time condensing that down to a much more manageable size.

Comment: @KubaOber If you think that the C++ community would be strongly opposed to these changes then you shouldn't make them.  If the community would be strongly opposed to the information then it wouldn't qualify as information widely accepted by the community as essential to asking a good question on that topic.

Comment: "you need to spent quite a lot of time condensing that down to a much more manageable size" Most people can easily digest practical examples. Given that we're talking about throwing code about, even carefully prepared code, it still can't be small even if I put very little verbiage around the code. I mean, I could be as succinct as formatting a big code blob with "DO" and "DON'T" columns. But it seems to defeat the purpose of being easy to understand.

Comment: @Servy You're characterizing the emergent behavior of a complex system, a.k.a. the community, as if it was one person who can rationally convince themselves of something, in an idealized setting. It won't work that way. It doesn't make the community bad as a whole, or its individual members bad, it's just that oftentimes emergent behavior is counterintuitive. Even if all those community members would love it everyone followed a bit more spelled-out process before throwing a very poor question around, I fully expect that they may object.

Comment: @KubaOber So you feel that you have advice that the overwhelming majority of C++ users would feel is vital information for users asking a C++ question to understand before asking a question, but that they would also strongly oppose anyone actually informing people of that information?  I...don't believe that would happen.  Either it's a strong sign that the community doesn't generally feel that that information is important for users asking questions to follow, or they wouldn't have a problem providing the information.

Comment: @Servy I guess I'll give it a shot, then, starting with adding a bit to the C++ wiki, and seeing what transpires. None of this is earth-shattering stuff, just a simple list of things to consider (how to massage the code, minimization strategies, if it crashes please post the backtrace, etc.)